# How to add values from one data frame to another based on a distance criteria.

Tags: r

I have two different datasets,

```
df1 <- data.frame(
x = c(1.25:10.25),
y = c(1.25:10.25),
val = sample(50:150, 100, replace = FALSE)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
x = c(1:10),
y = c(1:10),
val_2 = sample(50:150, 100, replace = FALSE)
)

ggplot(df1, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
geom_tile(aes(fill=val)) + coord_equal() +
scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high="red") + 
geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = y, size = val_2), shape = 21, colour ="purple")
```

the resulting plot looks like this,

[image]

I would like to assign the values from df1 to df2 based on the box in which the df2 bubbles lie.  The result I am looking for will be a copy of df2, but with an added column of df1 values.  So something like

`df2$val_1 <-`

and the right-hand side code might have some distance criteria.

Comment: is this example representative of the real problem or it does not include all characteristics of the entire population?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the sample data presented and the example to reproduce, the solution can be given by:

```
require(dplyr)
df2$val_1 <- left_join(df2,
                       df1 %>% mutate(x = round(x,0), y = round(y,0)),
                       by = c("x" = "x", "y" = "y")) %>%
        pull(val)
```

---

Instead, if you want to approach it using a more generalizable approach based on **distance**. I would suggest the following:

First of all, it is important to assign a `primary key` to both `data.frame` `df1` and `df2`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
        ID = seq.int(1:100),
        x = c(1.25:10.25),
        y = c(1.25:10.25),
        val = sample(50:150, 100, replace = FALSE)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
        ID = seq.int(1:100),
        x = c(1:10),
        y = c(1:10),
        val_2 = sample(50:150, 100, replace = FALSE)
)
```

We need to install `pdist` package because allow the computation of a distance matrix, in this solution using euclidean distance considering variables `x` and `y`

```
require(pdist)
dists <- pdist(df2[c("x", "y")],
               df1[c("x", "y")])
```

Let's convert the output of `pdist()` function to a matrix

```
dists <- as.matrix(dists)
```

Now, based on the resulting matrix, we want to obtain a `data.frame` that for each element of `df2` it gives us the ID of the **nearest element of `df1`**

```
assign_value <- data.frame(ID_df2 = df2$ID,
                           ID_df1 = apply(dists, 1, which.min))
```

We need to integrate the resulting 2-column `data.frame` with the `val` feature of `df1`:

```
assign_value <- left_join(assign_value,
                          df1[c("ID", "val")],
                          by = c("ID_df1" = "ID"))
```

Finally, we have obtained a data.frame with the following structure: "*each row refers to a unique element of `df2` and it is linked to the `ID` of the **nearest** element in `df1` and its `val`*":

```
  ID_df2 ID_df1 val
1      1      1  70
2      2      2 132
```

To obtain the final data.frame we just have to perform a simple left_join using the desired features.

```
alternative_solution <- dplyr::left_join(df2,
                        assign_value[c("ID_df2", "val")],
                        by = c("ID" = "ID_df2"))

> identical(df2$val_2, alternative_solution$val)
[1] TRUE
```